# how to make find one query after joining two collections

Tags: python-3.x, database, mongodb, flask

so i  have two collections in my database: `1st: user, and 2nd: books`. so i am joining these collections using `$lookup method`. after making `$lookup` query i am getting something like these (**see bellow**). which is desired.

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('5e2fd706829b686bd629b45e'), 'name': 'vatsalay khobragade', 'email': 'vatsalayvk1434@gmail.com', 'password': b'$2b$12$VmcHsxfx5TKmSfgWT9cqoe1xfL4mMMr9DRXqX2wlaj5oQ5BRaxbDe', 'address': 'rajnandgaon', 'location': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [20.9727404, 80.69155548263583]}, 'fulladdress': 'Rajnandgaon, Chhattisgarh, India', 'isVerified': True, 'donateList': [[{'bookid': ObjectId('5e314eed3f84e7cf7f0a5bfe')}], [{'bookid': ObjectId('5e315dc9a92ad961795d9718')}]], 'books': [{'_id': ObjectId('5e2af0e82b9a4157f000cad8'), 'bookname': 'javascript book', 'bookdesc': 'its a javascript book', 'donatedby': 'vatsalay khobragade'}, {'_id': ObjectId('5e314eed3f84e7cf7f0a5bfe'), 'bookname': 'biology book', 'bookdesc': 'its a biology book\r\n', 'donatedby': 'vatsalay khobragade'}, {'_id': ObjectId('5e315dc9a92ad961795d9718'), 'bookname': 'python 3 book', 'bookdesc': 'armin rochnaher', 'donatedby': 'vatsalay khobragade'}]}]
```

Now what i want is: **if a user in my app is searching for a book and if i have that book in these query result, i want to show the book information to the user which i have in this data  or result.** i dont know if i can make a `findOne` query in this data. how do i achive this ? Please Help ! I am using Flask and Flask_Pymongo.

Comment: Ok if you need to search a book, then query on books collection & get related users info(donors info), that you'll have a books info & users info as well !! Do you want me to give a query for that ?

Comment: i don't want to do that because this data is location based data i want to make query on this result.

Comment: what do you mean by location based data ? what do you mean by a user searching for a Book ? The query what you've already written - what is input for that (Are you passing `"bookid" : ObjectId("5e314eed3f84e7cf7f0a5bfe")`)?

Comment: my query so far: ```database = mongo.db.mylogin
 my_col = database.aggregate([{"$lookup" : {"from" : "books", "localField" : "name", "foreignField" : "donatedby", "as" : "books"}}])```

Comment: the ```name``` is corresponds to ```donatedby```

Comment: So you're inputting a user name means you’re searching for a user & his donated books !! If another user is searching for a specific book & you wanted to get that book & who donated it then it’s altogether a different task/query !! How can you use data of first query for second task ? You can only do it in UI code by caching existing data from query1 or if you wanted to happen it in mongo then just search for book in book collection ! Or last option is send a name of person 'X' & also a book name passed by other user 'Y' - get all details same way & filter for that book in result in same query

Comment: actually i have all the info about books in this query result(in key value pairs), like how's the donor and all of that, i just want to match the ```users query``` with the ```result``` and just  want to show three info: ```bookname, book description  and donated by```

Comment: Of a particular book - let's say `'javascript book'`? Are you inputting any reference like `_id` or `bookname` of that book in same query ?

Comment: you mean in the```$lookup``` query ? the user is searching for book by its name

Comment: I don't understand whether you're getting my point or not !! Please check back your requirement properly !! Do you want to search for a book or search for a user ? If you're searching for a particular book what is the input you wanted to provide in order to DB provide you a result ??